# How can I access System.Windows.Forms.Design.ParentControlDesigner?

Tags: c#, namespaces, custom-controls

Altough this seems like a stupid question, VS2010 tells mit, that System.Windows.Forms.Design contains only 9 classes, whereas MSDN list 20+.

All I want, is to write the following class(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973820.aspx):

```
public class DragDropControlDesigner : ControlDesigner {
      public override void Initialize(IComponent c) {
         base.Initialize(c);
         ((Control)c).AllowDrop = false;
      }
   }
```

Project references and user directives don't help.
I am even actively using the class with

```
[Designer("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ParentControlDesigner, 
 System.Design", 
 typeof(IDesigner))]
```

on one of my user controls.
I searched for tutorials and on forums for an answer: nothing. Is there someone out there, who has written a custom designer and can tell me how to solve this?

Comment: Are you targeting the "Client Profile" version of the Framework?

Comment: Control panel tells me, I have .Net 4 "Client Profile" as well as .Net 4 "Extended" installed. Any idea, if there is a setting in VS that determines, which one (if not both) are used?

Comment: Yes, I was talking about your project settings in VS. Right-click on the project in the Solution Explorer and click "Properties". Look what version of the framework you're targeting. I forget what the screen looks like, I don't have the .NET stuff installed on this computer.

Comment: Oh Gawd, thanks a lot. Seems I have to abandon that solution, since this would require the users to have the full version installed.

Comment: Yes, but there's not as much difference as you think between the full version and the Client Profile. You're only saving about 16%, as I recall. Only the developers (those who would be interacting with your form at design time) really need to have the full framework installed, and they will anyway—VS installs it by default.

Comment: Designers are used in Visual Studio.  You can safely assume that the user will have the full version of .NET installed when he runs VS.

Answer (score 15):

I know i'm very late, but as the second parameter of the DesignerAttribute indicates, this class is in the System.Design assembly.  If you add a reference to System.Design, you should see the class.

Comment: Cody Gray already solved it for me. It was about the target profile.